# How to download file from pod shell in Kubernates Dashboard?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, web-services, kubernetes, cloud

So, I need to reverse engineer how an application works and it is deployed on a kubernates pod. This has been assigned to me after the previous developers just "left".

I need to download some files from that pod. I access it using Kubernates Dashboard by clicking the View Logs Button of the Pod.

How can I copy files from this pod to my local? There is a zip file and I want to inspect and read it contents.

How can I download other files?

kubectl cp didn't work for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a first step please install [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/#kubectl).

Then make sure that you have access to `k8s` cluster where the pod is running. This is done via [kubeconfig](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/). Since you are on `AWS` it can be done with following command

```
aws eks update-kubeconfig --region region-code --name my-cluster
```

Next is just check execution of command:

```
kubectl cp <pod-name>:<fully-qualified-file-name> /<path-to-your-file>/<file-name> -c <container-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, seems like the terminal window you are showing is *inside* the pod, so there is no use for `kubectl`.

What you need is `kubectl` in your local terminal. You can follow Michal's answer on how to connect to the pod.